# Why I having multiple requests to the server when listening to socket event inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I am getting multiple requests although only one event is emitted inside node js server. I want to rerender my component only once when event is emitted from the server in order to notify the user that the has been completed successfully.
This is my custom hook for fetching data from the server:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export const useFetch = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const request = useCallback(async (url, method='GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            if(body) {
                body = JSON.stringify(body)
                headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            }

            const response = await fetch(url, {method, body, headers})
            const data = await response.json()

            if(!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(data.msg || 'Что-то пошло не так!')
            }

            setLoading(false)

            return data
        } catch (e) {
            setLoading(false)
            setError(e.message)
            throw e            
        }
    }, [])

    const clearError = () => setError(null)

    return [loading, error, request, clearError]
}
```

This is my home.js file code, where I am fetching data from the server:

```
const Home = () => {
    const [loading, error, request, clearError] = useFetch()
    const [tables, setTables] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {    
        const handleFetchTables = async() => {
            try {
                const data = await request('/api/table/getAllTablesForCash')
                setTables(data)
            } catch (_) {
                console.log(_.message)
                clearError()
            }
        }

        handleFetchTables()

        socketIO.on('new_order_finished', async() => handleFetchTables())
        socketIO.on('order_closed', async() => handleFetchTables())

    }, [request])


    const handleTables = () => {
        if(loading) return <CustomSpinner />
        if(error) return <NetworkError />
        return tables && (
            tables.length ? (
                <div style={styles.main}>
                    {
                        tables.reverse().map((t, i) => {
                            return (
                                <TableCard key={i} t={t} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            ) : (
                <EmptyBag />
            )
        )
    }

    return (
        <div style={styles.container}>
            <HomeHeader />
            {handleTables()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

[image].png

Comment: Help please! It is effecting performance a lot. Especially when I have more orders, it is fetching for about 21-22 times

Comment: Is it possible that `handleFetchTables` triggers `new_order_finished` or `order_closed` somehow? Also, why is `request` in the `useEffect` dependencies, when its identity does not change (due to `useCallback`)?

Comment: Place a a few `console.log`, it should make it clearer. The `handleFetchTables` runs in two cases: 1) as the effect runs 2) on socket events. The effect runs on mount, then once `request`'s identity changes. The identity of `request` does not change (it's returned by `useCallback`, and I don't see any errors in its usage), so we are left with two cases: 1) The component `Home` is in fact getting remounted (mounted + unmounted) multiple times for whatever reason, triggering the effect. 2) Socket events run multiple times.

Comment: I recommend you reduce this to a minimal, reproducible example. This will help in spotting the issue.

Comment: Also, you are NOT unsubscribing from the socket events once `Home` unmounts. Therefore once you navigate out of `Home` then back to `Home` again, you'll have more and more redundant listeners that send more and more requests every time you navigate back to `Home`. Webpack's dev server is reloading on every change of code and it doesn't unsubscribe from events either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys :)! Seems socket should be closed when unmounting component. ```socket.off(handleFetchTables)```. I included request dependency cuz I saw it in tutorial )). Tried removing it and it is working fine now ).

Answer (score 1):

In your home.js, the useEffect is called each time there's a change in the request. The useEffect block contains code that subscribes to the event emitted by the socket. So each time useEffect is being called for a change in 'request', you are creating another subscriber to the event. So if an event is fired, it'll call the subscribed function multiple times.

Try removing the [request] part from the current useEffect. If you really want to do something based on the change in the 'request' object, use another useEffect block and don't put the event subscriber in that. Or try unsubscribing in the starting of your current useEffect block, but it's not a good solution. Hope this'll solve your issue

Comment: Why would `request`'s identity change though? It's a function memo'd by `useCallback` with `[]` as deps, as far as I see.